# Watir: element exists but .exists? returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I'm using Watir on a Rails project to scrape the following page: https://icecat.biz/fr/search?keyword=3030050010763

I need to check if the `<a>` tag with the `'src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__descriptionTitle--8-vad'` class exists, which it does, but the .exists? method is returning `false`.

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto "https://icecat.biz/fr/search?keyword=3030050010763"
p b.a(:class => "src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__descriptionTitle--8-vad").exists?
```

I know the element exists because the following code is returning the href value of that same element:

```
b.a(:class => "src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__descriptionTitle--8-vad").href
```

I've used the .exists? method to check if some elements exist on other pages and it works fine. For example, this is returning `true`:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto "https://icecat.biz/fr/p/babyliss/bab5586e/hair+dryers-3030050010763-bab5586e-29245899.html"
p b.a(:data_type => "json").exists?
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The targeted element is being AJAX'd in.  If you add an arbitrary `sleep 5` statement/hack after the call to `goto`, the `exists?` call will return `true`.  You need to poll/wait for the element.  For reference: http://watir.com/guides/waiting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the product list being loaded asynchronously. As a result, you will see that `#exists?` has a different result based on when you run it:

- If you check right after visiting the page, while the spinner is still visible, `#exists?` will be `false`.
- If you wait for the product list to load, `#exists?` will be `true`.

You can see this clearly by checking `#exists?` multiple times after loading the page:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto "https://icecat.biz/fr/search?keyword=3030050010763"
5.times do
    p b.a(:class => "src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__descriptionTitle--8-vad").exists?
end
#=> false
#=> false
#=> true
#=> true
#=> true
```

Note that methods that interact with the element, such as `#href`, will automatically wait for the element to exist before taking action.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I thought that ```.exists?``` would also wait for the element to exist, but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is due to either:

1) a bug in `exists?` (not sure which version you are using) but quickly found this: https://github.com/watir/watir/commit/e036ffaa5d63e8c54c56c630ab7cba2f0bdce463

2) or some nuances outlined here: http://watir.com/staleness-changes/ (perhaps your code triggers this 'weird' behavior:

```
it 'returns different responses when called more than once' do
  browser.goto(WatirSpec.url_for('forms_with_input_elements.html'))
  element = browser.text_field(id: 'new_user_email').tap(&:exists?)

  browser.refresh       # all elements become stale

  expect(element.present?).to be false
  expect(element.present?).to eq true
end
```

Either way, the best way to find out what is really going on is to go to the source of your gem (wherever it is installed on your machine) and patch (edit) the method and see yourself what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it turns out that this had something to do with your second point - ```.exists?``` will not wait for the element to exist before taking action so that's why it can return something different if called multiple times.